# where can I find Java build 1.5.0_20_Java-RTS-2.2_fcs-b19_RTSJ-1.0.2 for download?

Tags: java

I am looking for a specific java version:

Java build 1.5.0_20_Java-RTS-2.2_fcs-b19_RTSJ-1.0.2

does anyone know where can i find it for download and install on Linux 5/6?

Thanks

Comment: Should it be assumed you've looked at oracle?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

According to some pages I've found, Java 2.2 RTS was only available via Sun Product Sales.  I guess that means you should contact Oracle.

I'm pretty sure that Java RTS is not a current Oracle product though.

(If you do manage to find a download link for the installer on the open internet, it is most likely an illegal copy ...)

Comment: I could not find it on the internet.
Thanks Stephen.

Comment: Like I said in my Answer, contact Oracle.